# can we use #define constant in struct declaration as array size?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am doing the following in C

```
#define MAX_DATA_SIZE 500;

struct reliable_state {

  char dataBuffer[MAX_DATA_SIZE]; 

}
```

i.e I want to use the #define constant as array size in structure declaration.
But above code gives weird error

```
.c:36: error: expected ‘]’ before ‘;’ token
```

So is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Remove the semicolon on your `#define` line.  It should be `#define MAX_DATA_SIZE 500`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can, just remove ';' in your define line:

```
#define MAX_DATA_SIZE 500
```

With define you have compiler will actually 'see' your struct definition as

```
char dataBuffer[500;];
```

which is clearly erroneous.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `#define`, the macro on the right side is defined "as is". E.g. here, you've just have to correct it to

```
#define MAX_DATA_SIZE 500  /* no semicolon */
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for a non-empty object-like macro definitions is

```
#define MACRO_IDENTIFIER    REPLACEMENT
```

Note that there is no terminating semicolon in this syntax, unlike for C declarations and statements. Your semicolon became part of the REPLACEMENT and was inserted where you used the macro identifier, yielding

```
char dataBuffer[500;];
```

which is a syntax error the compiler diagnosed.